# Dynamically adapt a div to full viewport and cover all the page on overflow - React / Next 13.3.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I want to set a div as container to cover all my viewport on normal cirumstances, but when an inner div overflows the container, the container needs to be 20px larger than the inner div. I have tried to use `ResizeObserver` to watch the inner div resizings, but this seems to not work as intended.

Here's a minimal example of what I've tried:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

function Test() {

    const containerDivRef = useRef(null);
    const childDivRef = useRef(null);

    const [initalPageSize, setInitialPageSize] = useState(0);

    function observeChildDivResize(){

        const childDiv = childDivRef.current;
        const containerDiv = containerDivRef.current;

        const mainPanelObserver = new ResizeObserver(() =>{
        
            if(containerDiv.scrollHeight > initalPageSize){
                containerDiv.style.height = (containerDiv.scrollHeight + 50).toString() + "px";
            }
            else{
                containerDiv.style.height = "100vh";
            }
        })

        mainPanelObserver.observe(childDiv);
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        observeChildDivResize();
    }, [initalPageSize])

    useEffect(() =>{
        setInitialPageSize(containerDivRef.current.height);
    }, [])

    return (
    <div ref={containerDivRef}
        style={{backgroundColor: "red", height: "100vh", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>

        <div ref={childDivRef}
            style={{width: "900px", height: "fit-content", backgroundColor: "white", marginTop: "50px", marginBottom: "50px"}}>

            <textarea/>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

I guess there are easier ways to do this, but I didn't find'em. Notice I use a `textarea` to test rezise, beacuse content on this will be dynamic